# Как убрать высоту элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Припустим есть 3 элемента расположены друг за другом( float:left ).
Нужно сделать высоту элемента =0/скрыть элемент, но забронировать место ширины ,которое он занимал.

Я не хочу,чтобы 2 и 3 передвинулись вперед.

Варианты display/overflow/opacity -не подходят ( они не бронируют ширину элемента).
Вариант делать margin не вариант!
Установка

```
.style.height=0+'px';
```

не помогает.
Помогите, кто чем может.

Comment: когда 0 - px не нужен. насчет opacity что-то мне не верится,

Comment: просто добавте `margin-left` следующему элементу равным ширине забронированного места

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так (у элемента, который нужно скрыть, но оставить занимаемое им место):

```
position: relative;
left: -9999px;
top: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте visibility:hidden;

Comment: Замечу, что тогда клики по блоку будут проходить

Comment: место резирвируется ширина и высота...Но высоту нужно сделать равну 0 чтобы нижний блок стал выше.